# VK API. Изменение расширенной информации о пользователе

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

[Сейчас тут имеется в виду вот [эта](https://vknet.github.io/vk/) библиотека под C#]

Хотелось бы изменить некоторые поля в информации о пользователе: его любимые книги, игры, его город и т.д. Получить их легко, а как изменить? Ответ можно дать и по общему VK API.

Comment: город, статус, день рождения можно поменять за счет  account.saveProfileInfo   https://vk.com/dev/account.saveProfileInfo а вот книжки видео музыка увлечения - вроде бы нет методов

Comment: Что, совсем нет? Я как-то год назад видел приложение, в котором возможно было изменять такие поля, но я что-то ничего не нашёл об этом.

Comment: Совсем нет ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  .... что за приложение это было?

Comment: Клиент VK под Windows. Я сам сейчас его делаю для себя, но как-то странно выходит: персональные поля получить можно, а изменить никак.

Comment: Ну у них там полно таких методов. Это уж вопрос им надо задать - почему так. А этот клиент если знаете как точно называется - можно посмотреть и декомпильнуть, разобрать и посмотреть..... возможно просто какими-нибудь старыми методами и версией пользуется, которые раньше были а сейчас все прикрыли, а про этот забыли, кто знает. а может и вовсе не при помощи апи, а хаком пользуется